# Search in Array or MySQL entries with hierarchical values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

I have a database with 5000 entries of local area codes to separate the area code from a phone number string. Area Codes could be a part of other Area Codes. For example

0212    Solingen

02129   Haan

The Area Code of Solingen is a Part of the Area Code of Haan.

1. Question: Should i store all entries in an array or should i search directly in SQL till the final result?
2. Question: How can i get the entrie with the most found digits while area codes can be double in array / SQL

The Code i use is

The Result is "03491 52023" which is wrong; It should be "034915 2023"

```
<?php
$area_codes = array( '0350', '034', '034915', '03491', '0348', '0349', '03491', '034916', '034917',);
$phone = '0349152023';

foreach ($area_codes as $code) {
  if (substr($phone, 0, strlen($code)) == $code) {
    $phone_string = substr($phone, 0, strlen($code))." ".substr($phone, strlen($code));
  }
}

if (!empty($phone_string)) {
    echo $phone_string;
}

else {
    echo "No AreaCode found.";
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sort the array so the longest ones are first. Then as soon as you find a match you can break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to sort array and you will get desired output:

**Working Demo**: https://eval.in/871329

```
$area_codes = array( '0350', '034', '034915', '03491', '0348', '0349', '03491', '034916', '034917',);
sort($area_codes);

$phone = '0349152023';

foreach ($area_codes as $code) {
    $subString = substr($phone, 0, strlen($code)); // stored in var so no need to re-code for substr
    if ($subString == $code) {
        $phone_string = $subString." ".substr($phone, strlen($code));
    }
}

if (!empty($phone_string)) {
    echo $phone_string;
}

else {
    echo "No AreaCode found.";
}
```

Output:

```
034915 2023
```

Comment: Hi Jigar, thanks for your help so much. Would You Use These Code, when the Array Contains 5000 entries? Do You think it is a Problem for the Performance.

Comment: updated my asnwer and I had just provided solution for your query and removed duplicate code,if are concerned about performance you can ask question to  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . You will get better answer there regarding performance and optimization